# Group rows based on gaps in time series

Tags: r

I have a timeseries of gps data, that needs to be segmented into smaller parts based on **gaps** in the time stamps.

As an example, consider the following data frame, I want to **add a segment number** that segments each 'chunks' of time stamps, effectively spitting the data each time there is a gap in the time series of at least **30 seconds**.

The resulting data.frame would look something like this:

```
   timestamp segment
1          1       1
2          3       1
3          5       1
4         10       1
5         42       2
6         45       2
7         92       3
8        156       4
9        160       4
10       162       4
11       163       4
12       164       4
13       200       5
14       203       5
```

Any way of doing this effectively? The data.frame is a grouped tbl_df (dplyr package) with several distinct time series and can be quite large.

Comment: Why in the world would you provide an HTML table when your question is about R? Please provide a `data.frame` object using the `dput` function.

Comment: Made it a bit more readable, thank you for the suggestion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your example data

```
t <- c(1, 3, 5, 10, 42, 45, 92, 156, 160, 162, 163, 164, 200, 203)
```

Segment numbers

```
s <- cumsum(c(TRUE,diff(t)>=30))
```

Output

```
data.frame(timestamp=t,segment=s)
```

```
   timestamp segment
1          1       1
2          3       1
3          5       1
4         10       1
5         42       2
6         45       2
7         92       3
8        156       4
9        160       4
10       162       4
11       163       4
12       164       4
13       200       5
14       203       5
```

Answer (score 0):

If the name of your `data.frame` is "df"

```
df$segment[1] <- 1

for (i in 2:nrow(df)) {
    if (df$timestamp[i] < (df$timestamp[i-1] + 30)) {
        df$segment[i] <- df$segment[i-1]
    } else {
        df$segment[i] <- (df$segment[i-1] + 1)
    }
}
```